# java socket connects to proxy instead of actual server

Tags: java, sockets, networking, proxy

When I try to do this:

```
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("My proxy", 80));
            Socket socket = new Socket(proxy);
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(url, 80),2000);;


            InputStream sIn = socket.getInputStream();
```

I can't get any input since my socket is connected to the proxy server rather than the url server and so i don't get any input stream. Any suggestions? And I need to do the connection on the network layer, so please don't suggest things like httpurlconnection or httpclient. Many thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain more on it with some output logs and any errors.Could you also show your url and the proxy names used as well.

Comment: @glegshot regarding to errors, I actually don't get any errors. It connects successfully, just somehow not to the url. My proxy is some local corporate proxy, and my url is a salesforce sandbox's url.

Comment: just to leave no stones unturned, have you read from the input stream as well.Usually a SOCKS proxy value should be passed on to the socket proxy constructor as well. Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);

Comment: What protocol does "salesforce sandbox" implement, is it HTTP like the port number 80 suggests? In HTTP, you need to send a request to get a response. The code included in the question only connects to the server but doesn't send a request.

Comment: @Joni, it's a https protocol. However, right now no matter what url i put (even an invalid one), my socket connect successfully. That's why i suspect it's connecting to the proxy.

Comment: @glegshot i have tried reading it, it's empty. My managing engineer told me that our corporate proxy type is a http proxy. I have also tried .SOCKS just in case, but it still connects to the proxy some how.

Comment: @punpun123, since its a HTTP protocol,have you tried to send HTTP request via socket output stream.Once you completely send the request,then you have to read the inputstream to get the response from the server.

Comment: Of course your socket is connecting to the proxy. This is how proxies work: you connect to the proxy and and ask it to do something in your behalf. What's important is what you do once the connection is established. Thus far there's no indication you're trying to use the connection, so naturally nothing is going to happen when you run the code.

Comment: @Joni I'm trying to test my tcp connection, not on the http level, so I can't really do GETs and POSTs. Is there a way to test my connection without going too high level? Something that works like an ICMP ping but on the network layer?

Comment: The TCP connection terminates at the proxy host.

Comment: @Joni so there is no way to work around this? Any other suggestions?

Comment: It's not really clear what problem you are trying to solve. If the connection is successful, you have a live TCP connection. The TCP connection terminates at the proxy host, if it terminated at the final destination host you would not be using a proxy.

Comment: *"no matter what url i put (even an invalid one), my socket connect successfully"* - This suggests an error or a misconfiguration in the proxy software implementation. The proxy should return an error response to the HTTP CONNECT request. This will be seen in Java as `Socket.connect` method throwing an exception